# Somewhat complex React function component declaration with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const withAuth = () => <OriginalProps extends {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<OriginalProps & IAuthContextInterface>
) => { }

(withAuth()(PrivateRoute)) // this is how the HOC called
```

Can someone explain this function declaration in layman terms? I know it is an HOC, but what is OriginalProps? the syntax is not clear?

I won't vague if OriginalProps is removed,

```
const withAuth = () => (
      Component: React.ComponentType<OriginalProps & IAuthContextInterface>
    ) => { }
```

Comment: This is a way to infer props type from wrapped component without specifying props type explicitly on `withAuth` call. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints . This isn't specific to React. Whether `React.ComponentType<OriginalProps & IAuthContextInterface>` is a suitable type for `Component` or not depends on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#), and `OriginalProps` is a *type variable* or *type parameter*.

> **Important!** Before you proceed, read the above link to understand the concept of *generic* first. Basic understand of generic is prerequisite to following explanation.

The syntax is a bit obfuscated because of the conciseness of arrow function, let's convert it back to old school `function`.

```
function withAuth() {
  return function<OriginalProps extends {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<OriginalProps & IAuthContextInterface>) { ... }
}
```

You specify generic type parameters within a pair of pointy brackets `<typeParam1, typeParam2>`. Parameter names are picked arbitrarily. Convention in TS is to use just capital letters, like `T, A, B`. That's what you usually see.

Here the author decides to give it a more meaningful name `OriginalProps`. Let's also convert it to conventional `T`, and get rid of the `extends {}` [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).

```
function withAuth() {
  return function<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T & IAuthContextInterface>) { ... }
}
```

Now it should be clear, `withAuth` is a function that returns an anonymous function. This anonymous function is also a generic function that takes one type parameter, which is *inferable* from the type of `Component` parameter.

The whole thing reads like this:

- We have this `T` type parameter, the type value of which we don't know yet, but it's related to the type value of `Component`.
- We require the type of `Component` parameter to be `React.ComponentType<Something>`, but that `Something` is yet to know.
- When we call `withAuth()(PrivateRoute)`, we can know what `Something` is from `PrivateRoute`.
- Also given that we already know `IAuthContextInterface`, we can know the exact type value of `T`, just like solving an equation:

```
Something = T + IAuthContextInterface
=> T = Something - IAuthContextInterface

// here =, +, - signs are just analogue, not real typescript operators
```

Comment: Thank you @hackape. Make sense!